# Not Able To Add A Variable As A Value In A Dictionary In Python

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I am trying to make a class of something like a calculator, which will take 2 numbers as inputs and do the addition/subtraction/multiplication/division on basis of what the user chooses.
But I'm getting and error when I'm trying to make a dictionary of the things in division. Here is my code below:

```
class Calculator:
    def __init__(self,number1,number2):
        self.number1 = number1
        self.number2 = number2
    def divide(self,number1,number2):
        quotient=0
        dividend=0
        divisor=0
        remainder=0
        quotient=int(number1/number2)
        dividend=number1
        divisor=number2
        remainder=number1%number2
        return {
            'Dividend':dividend
            'Divisor':divisor
            'Quotient':quotient
            'Remainder':remainder
        }
```

The problem is that the values of the dictionaries are giving me a Syntax Error. Also, I'm using PyCharm to run it.

Comment: What syntax error are you receiving?

Comment: Have you ever seen an example of a dictionary before?

Comment: use `:` instead of `=` in your dict

Comment: Dictionaries use `:`, not `=`.

Comment: You use a colon in a dictionary, not an equal sign. VTC as typo

Comment: Note that fixing the colons, while necessary, won't be enough.

Comment: @JoeThor This is the erro: 'Dividend'=dividend
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Oh ya I needed to use the colons and put commas. Well thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you set the dictionary using `=` rather than `:`, and elements must be separated by commas.

```
class Calculator:
    def __init__(self,number1,number2):
        self.number1 = number1
        self.number2 = number2
    def divide(self,number1,number2):
        quotient=0
        dividend=0
        divisor=0
        remainder=0
        quotient=int(number1/number2)
        dividend=number1
        divisor=number2
        remainder=number1%number2
        return {
            'Dividend': dividend,
            'Divisor': divisor,
            'Quotient': quotient,
            'Remainder': remainder
        }
```

Comment: It also needs commas.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code:

```
class Calculator:
    def __init__(self, number1, number2):
        self.number1 = number1
        self.number2 = number2


    def divide(self, number1, number2):
        quotient = 0
        dividend = 0
        divisor = 0
        remainder = 0
        quotient = int(number1 / number2)
        dividend = number1
        divisor = number2
        remainder = number1 % number2
        return {
            'Dividend': dividend,
            'Divisor': divisor,
            'Quotient': quotient,
            'Remainder': remainder
        }
```

When you create a dictionary you need to seperate items with `,` and any item need to look in this way `key:value`.

**Another Tip for your code**:
You use the variables `number1,number2` in the `__init__` and again in the function inside the class. If you want to access the variables you defined in the `__init__` you can do like this: `self.number1` (You can do the same with the second variable)